# How to setup One SSL certificate for Load Balancer in GCP with Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ssl-certificate, terraform, wildcard-subdomain, terraform-provider-gcp

- I have 2 services on **ONE GCP** instance: one runs on port 80, the other is  on port 4000.
- I have setup `google_compute_global_forwarding_rule`, `google_compute_target_https_proxy`,  `google_compute_url_map`, and `google_compute_backend_service` for **each service**.
- I have  one wildcard `google_compute_ssl_certificate` which will be used in **BOTH** `google_compute_target_https_proxy`.
- I have one `google_compute_instance_group` setup to route my services.
- All resources run on ONE GCP instance and create by Terraform.

Everything works correctly. Except my certificate said it is invalid (Unsecure site warning).
What am I doing wrong here?

Note: My certificate still works on other sites on different servers.

- I have created **another** `google_compute_ssl_certificate` and use it on one of the `google_compute_target_https_proxy` and everything (both services) works after that.

However, it is really confusing, since this is wildcard certificate. Why do I have to create another certificate resource to make it valid?

Comment: Edit your question with the actual error and details of the SSL certificate as seen in your browser. Normally you do not create multiple backends, you create one backend and multiple listeners (frontends).

Comment: cool. I got it. Thank you.